# Long Git branch names in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

We have a Git repo where some independent teams work. So we decided to use a schema for our feature branches `<team_name>/<JIRA_ticket_number>_<some_description>`.

Unfortunately, feature branch names are too long and it's hard to see in what branch do you work at this moment looking at IntelliJ IDEA status bar.
[image]

So the single way to see current branch name is to move cursor to the bottom right status bar corner either press mouse button on it or wait some time till pop-up balloon will be appeared. It too long :(

At the same time there is much free space in status bar. Is it a way to show a full Git branch name in IDE status bar or to see it somehow fast via some keyboard combination?

Comment: Follow this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-73669. It has major priority, but unfortunately no signs of progress... :( As a workaround you can press CTRL+V and then 7 (open VCS popup and then branches subsection). Whole branch name is shown at the bottom of the popup. Note that this shortcut is for OS X, it will probably be different on Linux/Win. You could also assign custom shortcut directly to Git/Branches in Settings/Keymap.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt thank you! I've already used the first approach